# Django admin page is missing CSS

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin

I am actually following a youtube tutorial for learning Django and admin site is not showing properly.
The admin tab in the video looks like this:
[image]

My admin tab however looks like this:
[image]

An answer in stack overflow suggested to put DEBUG = True in settings.py file. But it is already set to that in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably set `static` files' location the wrong way. Sending `settings.py` is needed for any further help.
You can check [this document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/) for default values.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to start a simple project using the instructions provided in this documentation [Django - Introduction tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/)

Initially, you can also try the following instructions to check it.

At first, install django (latest version) using the following command

```
python -m pip install django
```

Then, open a folder in which you would like to create a django project, and open the terminal in that folder, then paste the following code

```
django-admin startproject MyProject
```

Copy and paste the following two commands one-by-one,

```
py manage.py makemigrations
py manage.py migrate
```

After that, create a admin user by providing the e-mail, username and password through the following command as follows,

```
py manage.py createsuperuser
```

Now, copy and paste the link you get in the browser along with 'admin/', which will direct you to the admin login page as specified in the documentation